# Is it possible to select one input field and trigger a validation on that field only with Parsleyjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

Using [parsleyjs](http://parsleyjs.org/) I would like to trigger a validation on only one field so I was hoping that this would work:

```
$('.form-input-field').parsley().validate();
```

But it does not work. Calling .parsley().validate() on the form it self does work thought and validates the whole form:

```
$('.form').parsley().validate();
```

Is there a way to manually validate only a single element?

Why I want to do this is because an error message needs to be visible when the parsley is initialized or as soon as possible before the user actually interacts with the element (but as mentioned only for one field in the form).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this purpose, parsley has `data-parsley-group` attribute.
Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjn0obpc/5/). Also, check [official documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#usage-field)

So you field validation will look like

```
form.parsley().validate({group: 'group-1'});
```

Comment: Great answer, except it's `...validate({group: 'group-1'})`

Comment: @t3mplar, I saw this in the documentation but did not fully understand the capabiliites. Thanks for pointing this out.